# Cambiar leyenda en gráfica drilldown en Highcharts

Tags: php, script, highcharts

Buenos días tengo una pregunta fácil de explicar espero me puedan apoyar o saber si existe la manera de resolver esto.

Tengo una gráfica con **3 niveles** con drilldown en el primer nivel solo muestro dos barras y en ellas quiero manejar porcentaje **"%"** pero al pasar a los dos siguientes niveles de drilldown quiero manejar la leyenda  **"Minutos"**.

Les muestro con imágenes mi gráfica.
[image: Imagen correcta con porcentaje "%"]

Siguientes dos niveles de drilldown.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En estos dos niveles del drilldown ya me interesa manejar la palabra **"Minutos"** en lugar del **"%"**

Código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Tiempos perdidos. Febrero, 2020'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Minutos'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y} %'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} %</b><br/>'
    },

    series: [
        {
            name: "Tiempos perdidos",
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [<?php 
            $row = $results->fetch_assoc();
                $OEENameL = $row["OELost"];
                $OEENameL= round($OEENameL * 100);
                $OEEName= $row["OEE"];
                $OEEName= round($OEEName * 100);
                ?>
                {
                    name: "OEE LOST",
                    y: <?php echo $OEENameL; ?>,
                    drilldown: "OEE LOST"
                },
                {
                    name: "OEE",
                    y: <?php echo $OEEName; ?>,
                    drilldown: "OEE"
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
    drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'OEE LOST',
                id: 'OEE LOST',
                data: [<?php 
                while($Rowx2 = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    $CategoriaS = $Rowx2["categoria"];
                    $totalMinutes = $Rowx2["totalMinutes"];
                ?>{
                    name: '<?php echo $CategoriaS; ?>',
                    y: <?php echo $totalMinutes; ?>,
                    drilldown: '<?php echo $CategoriaS; ?>',
                },<?php } ?>]
            }, {
                id: 'Change Over',
                data: [
                <?php 
                while($Rowx2 = $RQuerySubx1->fetch_assoc()){
                    $TotalMinuteS = $Rowx2["totalMinutes"];
                    $SCategoria = $Rowx2["subcategoria"];
                ?>
                    [
                    '<?php echo $SCategoria; ?>', 
                    <?php echo $TotalMinuteS; ?>
                    ],<?php } ?>
                ]
            },{
                id: 'Downtime',
                data: [
                <?php 
                while($Rowx2 = $RQuerySubx3->fetch_assoc()){
                    $TotalMinuteS = $Rowx2["totalMinutes"];
                    $SCategoria = $Rowx2["subcategoria"];
                ?>
                    [
                    '<?php echo $SCategoria; ?>', 
                    <?php echo $TotalMinuteS; ?>
                    ],<?php } ?>
                ]
            },{
                id: 'Lost Time',
                data: [
                <?php 
                while($Rowx2 = $RQuerySubx2->fetch_assoc()){
                    $TotalMinuteS = $Rowx2["totalMinutes"];
                    $SCategoria = $Rowx2["subcategoria"];
                ?>
                    [
                    '<?php echo $SCategoria; ?>', 
                    <?php echo $TotalMinuteS; ?>
                    ],<?php } ?>
                ]
            },{
                id: 'Planned Downtime',
                data: [
                <?php 
                while($Rowx2 = $RQuerySubx4->fetch_assoc()){
                    $TotalMinuteS = $Rowx2["totalMinutes"];
                    $SCategoria = $Rowx2["subcategoria"];
                ?>
                    [
                    '<?php echo $SCategoria; ?>', 
                    <?php echo $TotalMinuteS; ?>
                    ],<?php } ?>
                ]
            }]
        }
});
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Scripts Graficas -->
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
 <title>Graficas</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Tiempos perdidos. Febrero, 2020'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Minutos'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y} %'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} %</b><br/>'
    },

    series: [
        {
            name: "Tiempos perdidos",
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [                {
                    name: "OEE LOST",
                    y: 33,
                    drilldown: "OEE LOST"
                },
                {
                    name: "OEE",
                    y: 67,
                    drilldown: "OEE"
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
    drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'OEE LOST',
                id: 'OEE LOST',
                data: [{
                    name: 'Change Over',
                    y: 48,
                    drilldown: 'Change Over',
                },{
                    name: 'Downtime',
                    y: 337,
                    drilldown: 'Downtime',
                },{
                    name: 'Lost Time',
                    y: 47,
                    drilldown: 'Lost Time',
                },{
                    name: 'Planned Downtime',
                    y: 21,
                    drilldown: 'Planned Downtime',
                },]
            }, {
                id: 'Change Over',
                data: [
                                    [
                    'Type 2', 
                    48                 ],                ]
            },{
                id: 'Downtime',
                data: [
                                    [
                    'Material', 
                    29                 ],                    [
                    'Placement Machine', 
                    206                 ],                    [
                    'SPI/AOI/Placement Machine', 
                    102                 ],                ]
            },{
                id: 'Lost Time',
                data: [
                                    [
                    'Material', 
                    22                 ],                    [
                    'Micro-Stop', 
                    10                 ],                    [
                    'Reel change', 
                    15                 ],                ]
            },{
                id: 'Planned Downtime',
                data: [
                                    [
                    'Meeting', 
                    21                 ],                ]
            }]
        }
});
</script>
```

Comment: podrias agregar solo el codigo html y js dandole click derecho ver codigo fuente y colocandolo en la opcion fragmento javascript!

Comment: @Bryro Listo amigo

Comment: si te e entedido lo que debes hacer es solo cambiar `dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y} %'
            }` por esto `dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y} Minutes'
            }` si lo que quieres el el tooltips solo debs cambiar `pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} %</b><br/>'` por  esto `pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} Minutos</b><br/>'` como vez en ambos casos solo es cambiar `%` por la palabra `Minutos`

Comment: @Bryro Ok eso es correcto pero me cambia todos los niveles bro, se supone que el primer nivel debe quedar con "%" y los demas drilldown con "Minutos"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes añadir el cambio dentro de cada serie del drilldown, he puesto el ejemplo en 'OFF LOST', donde añado un nuevo dataLabels.

```
dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.y} MINUTES'
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Scripts Graficas -->
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
 <title>Graficas</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Tiempos perdidos. Febrero, 2020'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Minutos'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y} %'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} %</b><br/>'
    },

    series: [
        {
            name: "Tiempos perdidos",
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [                {
                    name: "OEE LOST",
                    y: 33,
                    drilldown: "OEE LOST"
                },
                {
                    name: "OEE",
                    y: 67,
                    drilldown: "OEE"
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
    drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'OEE LOST',
                id: 'OEE LOST',
dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.y} MINUTES'
        },
                data: [{
                    name: 'Change Over',
                    y: 48,
                    drilldown: 'Change Over',
                },{
                    name: 'Downtime',
                    y: 337,
                    drilldown: 'Downtime',
                },{
                    name: 'Lost Time',
                    y: 47,
                    drilldown: 'Lost Time',
                },{
                    name: 'Planned Downtime',
                    y: 21,
                    drilldown: 'Planned Downtime',
                },]
            }, {
                id: 'Change Over',
                data: [
                                    [
                    'Type 2', 
                    48                 ],                ]
            },{
                id: 'Downtime',
                data: [
                                    [
                    'Material', 
                    29                 ],                    [
                    'Placement Machine', 
                    206                 ],                    [
                    'SPI/AOI/Placement Machine', 
                    102                 ],                ]
            },{
                id: 'Lost Time',
                data: [
                                    [
                    'Material', 
                    22                 ],                    [
                    'Micro-Stop', 
                    10                 ],                    [
                    'Reel change', 
                    15                 ],                ]
            },{
                id: 'Planned Downtime',
                data: [
                                    [
                    'Meeting', 
                    21                 ],                ]
            }]
        }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias ya quedo solucionado, modificare tu codigo para tambien poner la leyenda minutos en el ultimo nivel del drilldown n.n

Answer (score 0):

lo que debes hacer es agregarle una propiedad en este caso usaremos `type` el nombre no es importante es solo para hacer referencia a que queremos `Minutos` o `%`

## ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Scripts Graficas -->
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
 <title>Graficas</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Tiempos perdidos. Febrero, 2020'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Minutos'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y} {point.type}' // utilizamos nuestra propiedad type
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} {point.type}</b><br/>'
    },

    series: [
        {
            name: "Tiempos perdidos",
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [                {
                    name: "OEE LOST",
                    y: 33,
                    drilldown: "OEE LOST",
                    type: 'Minutes', // agregamos la propiedad type
                },
                {
                    name: "OEE",
                    y: 67,
                    drilldown: "OEE",
                    type: '%', // agregamos la propiedad type
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
    drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'OEE LOST',
                id: 'OEE LOST',
                data: [{
                    name: 'Change Over',
                    y: 48,
                    drilldown: 'Change Over',
                },{
                    name: 'Downtime',
                    y: 337,
                    drilldown: 'Downtime',
                },{
                    name: 'Lost Time',
                    y: 47,
                    drilldown: 'Lost Time',
                },{
                    name: 'Planned Downtime',
                    y: 21,
                    drilldown: 'Planned Downtime',
                },]
            }, {
                id: 'Change Over',
                data: [
                                    [
                    'Type 2', 
                    48                 ],                ]
            },{
                id: 'Downtime',
                data: [
                                    [
                    'Material', 
                    29                 ],                    [
                    'Placement Machine', 
                    206                 ],                    [
                    'SPI/AOI/Placement Machine', 
                    102                 ],                ]
            },{
                id: 'Lost Time',
                data: [
                                    [
                    'Material', 
                    22                 ],                    [
                    'Micro-Stop', 
                    10                 ],                    [
                    'Reel change', 
                    15                 ],                ]
            },{
                id: 'Planned Downtime',
                data: [
                                    [
                    'Meeting', 
                    21                 ],                ]
            }]
        }
});
</script>
```